# Travelling to the US from Argentina, what do I need?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, covid-19, argentina

I am an Argentinian citizen living in Argentina, and I have a valid tourist visa for the US (got it in 2019, it's valid for 10 years). I'm planning on going to the AWS Re:Invent conference in Las Vegas on Nov 29th to Dec 3rd, staying a couple more days in Las Vegas, and visiting some other cities in the US before coming back to Argentina.

My question is, what do I need to maximize my chances of entering the US, or minimize the trouble?

I already have:

- Tickets for the conference
- Hotel reservations
- Two shots of the AstraZeneca COVID-19 vaccine and the corresponding certificate from Argentina (which I don't think counts as a "passport", but it's the legal paper we get here)

I don't have my plane tickets yet, so I have some margin as to which countries I would "visit" on the way to the US (if it were up to me I would just fly straight there). Some options include Panama and Mexico from what I researched. I'm mentioning them in case there's any ban or requirements related to those countries.

I'm not planning on working while in the US, I don't work for a US company, and I have been to the country twice when I was underage (20+ years ago) and to my knowledge did everything legally (I was 9 years old, but I think they would have rejected my visa if I hadn't). Also, I have very strong roots here in Argentina and wouldn't stay illegally in the US for any reason, and I would very much like to go back for the same conference next year.

I'm asking partly because I'm unaware of the restrictions imposed due to COVID-19, and partly because I think getting advice is a good idea.

Thanks!

Comment: Is your visa B1/B2 or only B2? I know of a few cases of people with only a B2 (tourism) visa that tried to get in for a professional conference and were denied entry because business visits are B1 visa (YEAH)